# Drag Text From External Domain iFrame To Droppable Element In Parent Window?

Tags: jquery, iframe, draggable, droppable

I am building a web application with a requirement to allow users to drag text from an iframe (src could be from any external domain) to a droppable element in my parent window. While I can easily get a handle on the iFrame window, I get the expected security errors when I attempt to select data from within the iFrame.

Currently, I am playing around with code copied from a Mark Kolich post on his website. I have modified it to look for selected text in an iFrame. I have tried modifying the URL fragment (i.e., adding "#crunch" to the end of the URL) based on what I read here: http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

... but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I haven't moved beyond simply trying to get hold of the selected text, yet.

Is there a way to capture text highlighted inside an iFrame (pointing to an external domain) so that it can be dragged to an element on the parent window?

Here is the code:

```
if(!window.crunch){
  crunch = {};
}

crunch.Selector = {};
crunch.Selector.getSelected = function(){

    var s = $("#xFrameWindow").attr('src');
    $("#xFrameWindow").attr('src', s + "#crunch")

    var t = '';

    if (window.frames["xFrameWindow"].getSelection) {
        t = window.frames["xFrameWindow"].getSelection();
    } else if(window.frames["xFrameWindow"].document.getSelection) {
        t = window.frames["xFrameWindow"].document.getSelection();
    } else if(window.frames["xFrameWindow"].document.selection) {
        t = window.frames["xFrameWindow"].document.selection.createRange().text;
    }

    return t;
}

crunch.Selector.mouseup = function(){
  var st = crunch.Selector.getSelected();
  if(st!=''){
    alert("You selected:\n"+st);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).bind("mouseup", crunch.Selector.mouseup);
});
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with a content inventory app of mine. Sorry you never got an answer. It looks like dragging content from external sources is near impossible